# Patterns and good practices on securing wcf service

Tags: c#, wcf

I am building a wcf service that needs to be secured as information that the client inter-exchanges with the service is sensitive to the company. I am planning to have it hosted on iis6. What would be the best practice to make sure that nobody but the client application can call the service to get/set data?

The service calls need to happen under the user's real identity as all the calls have to be monitored and audited. I am planning to use PolicyInjection for audit calls.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It all depends.

But basically there are two main approaches:

- Transport security with SSL with basicHttpBinding
- SSL security with wsHttpBinding

If you provide more information, I should be able to help you more.

There are certain aspects of security:

1) Data integrity: no-one has tampered with data but the data itself are not secret. This is achieved by signing.

2) Data security: This is so that no one could see sensitive/secret information. This is by encryption.

3) Authentication: this is by sending username/password or using certificates. This makes sure the person is the same who is claiming.

4) Authorization: This is to make sure the person has access to the specific features in the service.

Comment: Ok, the service calls need to happen under the user's real identity as all the calls have to be monitored and audited. So I need to impersonate the call to the service and verify that the call is performed under that user id.

Comment: Update your question then. Also you do not need impersonation, you just need authentication/authorization.